# Quadratic Regression with a proportion scale in SPSS?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, spss, nonlinear-regression

I want to perform a Quadratic regression in SPSS. The dataset includes two variables:

- Independent variable = the **proportion** of hours worked from home -> (ranges from: 0.00 - 1.00)
- Dependent variable = work engagement (ranges from: 0 - 5)

My problem is how to perform a Quadratic regression in SPSS?

The problem: one of the steps of a Quadratic regression analyses in SPSS is to compute a to create a variable that is squared. But, with a proportion-scale (0.00 - 1.00), this is very different as the size decrease. For example 0.2 - 0.04.

Question:

- What is the best way to perform a quadratic regression analyses with a proportion data scale as independent variable?
- How to compute the new squared variable?

Example of the normal procedure (not applicaple here, because square is not possible):
https://www.statology.org/quadratic-regression-spss/

Comment: "*But, with a proportion-scale (0.00 - 1.00), this is very different as the size decrease*". Why this is a problem?

Comment: Well, the size of the proprotion decreases  when squeared:

For example:
0.80*0.80 = 0.64
0.40*0.40 = 0.14
0.20*0.20 = 0.04

The new computed (squared) variables are totally different and decreases in stead of multiply with squared function.

See attached the example, 5*5 = 25 - 6*6 = 36 -> it increases.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could rescale 0-1.00 by multiplying by 100 (so the range would become 0-100), and then the squared value would not decrease any more. But I still don't get why this decrease is a concern.

Comment: What is the function to compute a new variable to square when the proportion value decreases?

Comment: The difference in sizes between proportions and their squares is of no consequence (it's actually meaningless, since the two are in different units anyway).  What really matters is that you should be concerned about any sizable variations in the duration of time in which each proportion was measured, because that affects the relative precision of the data and ought to be accommodated by adopting a suitable model or at least with weights in an ordinary least squares regression.

Comment: So, what about my variable ´proportion of hours worked from home a week´. It compared the total working hours with the proportion hours worked from home a week. And measured in a range of 0.00 - 1.00. For example: 0.50 when someone worked 50% from home compared with the total hours a week. > Is a quadratic regrssion possible with these data?

Comment: So i can just performan a Quadratic analyses with a proportion scale?

Comment: Sure, a quadratic regression is possible.  It is, after all, purely a mathematical algorithm with truly minimal requirements for success.  But if some of your subjects worked only a couple hours a week and others worked a hundred hours a week, some attention to this information will improve the results and make your conclusions more accurate and reliable.